# How to set a String parameter in a constructor equal to the contents of a CSV file?

Tags: java, string, constructor, csvreader

I'm trying to write a constructor for a class I have called "CSVGameData", which is meant to feed certain list arrays in my abstract class called "GameData". The parameters I have for my constructor are two strings which are meant to basically take the contents of two different CSV files, however I don't think I've done this before so I'm quite unfamiliar with how I'm supposed to set these two string parameters equal to their respective CSV files. (I have a CSV Reader file already written if that helps)

Comment: Can you please add the code to your question instead of describing it? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.